# Javascript/jQuery go to next input/select change select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, key, simulate

I write this script to simulate tab key. I mix 2 different examples from here and work fine only for inputs.

My script is

```
$("#home").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey && ( event.which === 39 ) ) {
    var target = document.activeElement;
        var next = target;
        while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
            if (next == null)
                break;
            if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" || next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "select") {
                next.focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have two problems.
Firstly with select input

```
<select id="position" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="position" form="athlets_data" style="width:175px">
     <option name="1">1</option>
     <option name="2">2</option>
     <option name="3">3</option>
     <option name="4">4</option>
</select>
```

when select input is focus and i press ctr and right arrow (as defined by script to go to next input) change the value to the next and then focus the next input.
i want to select an option and then with ctrl and right arrow to go to next input.

The second problem:

I have split my form with two divs right column and left column so when I click on a left's div input and use my script (ctrl and right arrow) to tab inputs, when go to last input can't move to the first input at the right div.

is there any idea?

Thanks in advance

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active row" style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <h3 style="color:#06F">Στοιχεία ασθενή</h3>
    <br>
    <form action="add_new_patient_card.php" id="patient_data" class="redirected_form" method="post">
    <div id="patient_data_left_column" class="col-md-5">
        <a>Lastname: </a>
        <input id="lastname" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="lastname" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Firstname: </a>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="firstname" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Fathers name: </a>
        <input id="fathersname" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="fathersname"  />
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Position: </a>
        <select id="position" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="position" form="athlets_data" style="width:175px">
            <option name="1">1</option>
            <option name="2">2</option>
            <option name="3">3</option>
            <option name="4">4</option>
</select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>AMA: </a>
        <input id="ama"  type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="ama"  />
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Birthday: </a>
        <input id="bday" type="date" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="bday" style="width:175px"  />
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Sex: </a>
        <select id="sex" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="sex" form="patient_data" style="width:175px">
            <option name="male">male</option>
            <option name="female">female</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div id="patient_data_right_column" class="col-sm-5">
        <a>Phone: </a>
        <input id="phone" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="phone" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Mobile: </a>
        <input id="mobile" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="mobile" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Fax: </a>
        <input id="fax" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="fax" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Email: </a>
        <input id="email" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="email" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Address: </a>
        <input id="address" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="address" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>City: </a>
        <input id="city" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="city" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a>Country: </a>
        <input id="country" type="text" class="toNextWithSimulateTab" name="country" value="">
    </div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OUFF that was so hard but i did it hihihi here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b9aovLr8/1/)

```
$(".toNextWithSimulateTab").keydown(function(event)
{
    if( event.ctrlKey && ( event.which === 39 ) ) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next(".toNextWithSimulateTab").focus();
        if($(this).is(":last-child") && $(this).parent().attr("id") == "patient_data_left_column")
        {
            $(this).parent().next().find(".toNextWithSimulateTab:first-child").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it works on chrome but in firefox the select still change OMG

Comment: Thanks for answer !!!!really working but i see something wrong in my posted code fore some reason all text Labels for each input disappeared so look the edit. i use your code with that html and dont go to next input.

Comment: hey sorry , i forget to tell you to remove all <br> between input , i changed it to margin-top in the css for spacement between input

Comment: oh sorry now i noticed the css part.. nice so about <a> tags is there any way to put labels for each input?

Comment: hey , yea you can no problem sorryfor the late response, was working

Comment: not working. i add the edited code without <br> but with <a>. pff i cant understand why... its seems that search the next object if have this class, if not stay at the same input.